# Vagrant boxes: alternative download links

Tags: vagrant

I'm trying to download one of the vagrant's box, but their server is painfully slow at this moment. Is there a public mirror for them? I want to download the precise64.box file.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Try the more reliable ones:

- [Vagrant Cloud Images (Ubuntu)](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/)
- OpsCode [bento](https://github.com/opscode/bento) (Ubuntu, Debian, CentOS)

In addition to vagrantbox.es (a bit out-dated).

Answer (score 6):

I found a mirror for the boxes on vagrantboxes.es on this location: 
http://mirror.hdcore.eu/vagrant/boxes/

Comment: Also available via FTP - ftp://mirror.hdcore.eu/vagrant/boxes/

Comment: not available as for 11 mar

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few links:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1537815/precise64.box

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14292474/vagrantboxes/precise64-ruby-1.9.3-p194.box

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/squishy.vagrant-boxes/precise64_squishy_2013-02-09.box

Hope that helps!

Reference:
http://www.vagrantbox.es/

Comment: Thank you for this answer, @Mingyu. I found www.vagrantbox.es yesterday but i think their links are slow too. Is there another similar site? Btw, thank you for the dropbox links.

Comment: I'm not aware of any, they claim to be *the* hub and possibly are it... most publicly released boxes seems to reside on Dropbox.

Comment: Another option is to create a box yourself, which is not that complicated.

Comment: BTW, once you run `vagrant box add` command once, you don't have to do it anymore.  Why do you care about speed so much?

Comment: @Mingyu, I was downloading at a 3KB/s or less rate a file of 700MB. The estimative was around 22 hours to complete. But the worst part is that without a downloader manager any error could cause the failure of the whole operation. It wasn't my connection, it was the server passing through a bad moment. So the I wanted another option.

Comment: Searching I found out about making my own box. But in the end I downloaded a box from one of these links and added the box from a local file. Thank you for the help!